# How to connect IBM Watson Assistant to a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-functions

So I have created a basic Watson Assistant Chatbot and a basic MySQL Database and I want to connect them together, for the Watson Assistant to extract something from it.

Here's the scenario as follows:

The Watson Assistant will ask the user to authenticate himself with his Client_ID and his password, if  the Chatbot recognizes these credentials, it should great the user by his first name.

ex: `"Welcome <first_name(from MySQL DB that I created)> how my I help you?"`.

Note that my MySQL DB contains these columns: `client_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`. I couldn't find anything none other than people using IBM Cloud resources such as DB2 which are not free to use.

I even tried this php code in the IBM Cloud Functions to provide a webhook:

```
<?php
function main(array $args) : array {

    // Retrieve client_id from Watson Assistant
    $clientid = $args['clientid'];

    // Set up MySQL database credentials
    $host = '';
    $port = ;
    $dbname = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    // Connect to MySQL database
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check for connection errors
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        return ['error' => 'Failed to connect to MySQL database: '.$conn->connect_error];
    }

    // Construct and execute MySQL query
    $sql = "SELECT first_name FROM clients WHERE client_id = $clientid";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // Check for query errors
    if (!$result) {
        return ['error' => 'Failed to execute MySQL query: '.$conn->error];
    }

    // Retrieve result and return as array
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row) {
        $response = ['first_name' => $row['first_name']];
    } else {
        $response = ['error' => 'Client ID not found in database'];
    }
    return $response;
}
?>
```

**it showed this error:**

> {   "error": "The action did not return a dictionary or array." }

Please if there's a solution for my problem or if any other way to do what I asked for I would much appreciate it.

I tried everything and I got nothing.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: I suppose the first question shoudl be "What form does `$clientid` take"?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's an int

Comment: Well in that case its the wrong int, because the query is not returning any resultset

Comment: _Although I would be tempted to add some error reporting_ If you are using PHP < 8.0, to get errors out of PHP _even in a LIVE environment_ add these 4 lines **temporarily, while debugging**, 
to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.
___Just in case there is a real error somewhere___

Comment: This is the IBM Cloud solution tutorial showing how to integrate Watson Assistant with a database system: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson Instead of using the Db2 interface, just use a SQL interface or database wrapper of your choice.

Comment: If its generating that error, then the `fetch_assoc()` did not return a row, so the query either failed or found nothing that matches the `clientid` you passed it.  SIMPLES